# "something (being) + past participle" vs "present participle + something"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Are these equivalent in meaning? I think I can also omit "being" and I can not discern any difference between them. If there are any, I appreciate it if you could explain.

> 1 The process commences with **fresh oranges (being) delivered** to a factory.
> 2 The process commences with **delivering fresh oranges** to a factory.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the second one because it suggests that the people who deliver the oranges are going to continue the process, which presumably isn't the case.

Comment: Do you also use "being" in the first one or can we omit it?

Comment: Yes, I would use _being_ - or you could say _with the delivery of fresh oranges_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference that could be gleaned is that (1) suggests the narrator may have some part in the delivery.

*"1 The process commences with fresh oranges (being) delivered to a factory."*

The oranges are delivered as a background activity in which the narrator has no part.

*"2 The process commences with delivering fresh oranges to a factory."*

Rather makes it sound as if the narrator is taking part in the delivery process.

Comment: The narrator, or the people performing the process? How could the narrator implicated by merely describing a process?

Comment: That is what narration is. Describing something - particularly a set of actions.

Comment: @gotube Is my first example actually the reduced form of "The process commences with fresh oranges which are delivered to a factory." ??

Comment: @PRL75 Yes, narration is when I describe something, not when I suggest that I myself have some part in it. The narrator is a 3rd party observer describing the scene unless they directly implicate themselves in it, usually by referring to themselves in the first person. This narration doesn't include any first person so I'm wondering why you think the person saying that sentence actually does the delivery.

Comment: @alireza No, the process begins with *the delivery* of oranges, not with oranges themselves.

Comment: @gotube  Isn't "The process commences with fresh oranges being delivered to a factory."  the reduced form of any other sentences and clauses?